# debug_backtrace() trigger memory allowance issue

Tags: php, debugging, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, debug-backtrace

I am debugging a Joomla website. For learning purpose, I just want to see which file calls/requests a module's *modulename*.php file, so I put `print_r(debug_backtrace())` in the top line of the *modulename*.php file, but an error triggered saying:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   98570240 bytes)

I am stuck here. Can someone give me an brief explanation why `debug_backtrace()` fails in this circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

Use flag `DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS`, e.g. `print_r(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS));`

If you want to display pretty stacktrace with parameters passed to functions, I recommend use my library [error-dumper](https://github.com/awesomite/error-dumper), [see an example](https://awesomite.github.io/error-dumper/examples/exception.html) how it works.